# How to match last occurrence in a string with Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rubocop

Hi I am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I have a pattern to find time from a string as follows:-

```
time_pattern = /(\d{2}\:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{2}\:\d{2})/
time = mystr[time_pattern]
```

It retuns the first matching time in the string for example if there are two times are present in the string "14:04" and "14:05" it will always return the first one which is "14:04". i need to find the second one. Please help me to find the second match using regex. I have also tried the scan method like:-

```
time = params.to_s.scan(time_pattern).uniq.flatten.last
```

But my rubocop throws an error `Methods exceeded maximum allowed ABC complexity (1)`
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestion for readability: `\d\d` does the same as `\d{2}` but is 1 character shorter + more readable IMO. Also, you should be able to do `/\d\d\:\d\d(\:\d\d)?/` (see here: http://rubular.com/r/UX13pdJZfm). Btw, with this Regexp, `99:99:99` is matched

Comment: @MrYoshiji but on the other side of the argument: `\d\d` adds unnecessary computation, but yes your second part is much better `\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?` or even `\d{2}(?::\d{2}){1,2}`. Also, `:` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: With `scan`, you need the version with a non-capturing group, and I'd use a word boundary: `params.to_s.scan(/\b\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?\b/).uniq.flatten.last`

Comment: And to answer how to match the last occurrence: `params.to_s[/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)/, 1]`

Comment: it still returns the first occurrence. please help

Answer (score 2):

#### Last Regex Match

To get the last match you can simply call [`#last`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-last) on the [`#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-scan) result.

```
regex = /(\d{2}\:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{2}\:\d{2})/ # original
# or
regex = /\d{2}(?::\d{2}){1,2}/ # kudos @ctwheels

string = '12:01, 12:02, 12:03:04, 12:05'

string.scan(regex).last
#=> "12:05"
```

#### ABC-Metric

The ABC Metric is more complex and would require having a look at your whole method. But here is a blog post that explains it pretty well: [Understanding Assignment Branch Condition](http://redgreenrepeat.com/2017/01/20/understanding-assignment-branch-condition/)

Another options is to change the max ABC size in the RuboCop settings. Have a look at the [RuboCop Configuration Documentation](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.52/configuration.html) and the [default configuration](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/d953a6f2720128563daa641689607bae99bc810f/config/default.yml#L1504) (Metrics/AbcSize max size is set to 15 by default).

Comment: Thanks but when i use scan with last it increase my codes complexity as i am using rspec-rubocop.

Comment: @awsmsid `string.scan(regex).last` is just 1 more branch than`string[regex]` and that doesn't do the job. Also the ABC size is not depended on that single call, you could also have a look at your other code (in that method) and see if there is room for optimization. Or maybe split up the method into multiple smaller methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following expression: `/(\d{2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)/g`.

Here is an example of it running in `ruby`:

```
re = /(\d{2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)/
str = ' "14:04" and "14:05"'

# Get matches
matches = str.scan(re)

# Get last match
matches = str.scan(re)

# Get last match
lastMatch = str.scan(re).last[0]

# Print last match
puts lastMatch.to_s
# OUTPUT => "14:05"

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I updated it. I had been looking at another PHP question.

Comment: @Tony although this is now ruby, it still doesn't answer the *whole* question.

Comment: @Tony that's better, you don't need to escape the `:` though

Comment: @Tony I'd also suggest dropping capture groups: `/\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?/` or printing will print an array instead of just the matched string.

Comment: Hey my regex is working but its returns only the first match in the string i want the last match in the string please help. i also tried time = mystr[time_pattern] but the result is same.

Comment: @Tony it returns [nil]

Comment: @awsmsid `str.scan(re)` should return an array of matches. Just use the last one.

Comment: @awsmsid So the problem was because the regex was returning the 2nd capture group: `(:\d{2})?` and not the full match. To fix this i was able to wrap the expression in another group like this: `(\d{2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)`. Your matches will now return 2 elements. The first is the full capture group and the last is the seconds capture group.

Comment: Thanks let me try this.

Comment: This is still a dangerous answer since the regex is flawed. The group should be non-capturing. Currently when you call *#last* on the *#scan* result you get an array `["14:05", nil]` back.